# How to combine app.get and app.post in Express?

Tags: node.js, express

I am working with facebook app canvas which requires post.
I am using express to handle `app.post('/')` and `app.get('/')`. Is it possible to combine these in a single function?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Aside of binding same function to `POST` and `GET` as suggested by JustSid in other answer you may use `app.all('/', handler)` to route all request types to function.

Comment: +1 Much better way than mine! (And I also learned something too :)

Comment: isn't .all also taking care of all the other http verbs like put, delete?

Comment: @PeterM, yes it is, if you need to take care of 'em than `all` isn't for you ;)

Comment: Thanks!  NEWB ALERT: Can you run app.post() alone, or do u always need app.get()?

Comment: @Squirrl, sure you can, just use the [verb](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.VERB) for method you need to handle

Answer (score 7):

You can have a single function to handle both, post and get:

```
function sharedHandler(req, res)
{
   // Some custom logic here
}

app.get('/', sharedHandler);
app.post('/', sharedHandler);
```